# Merging dataframes and replacing values with multiple conditions in R (1 > 0 > NA)

Tags: r, replace, merge, append, conditional-statements

This is my first time posting, so I apologize if I don't get the lingo right. I've been reading a lot of previous posts but still can't figure out my merge and replace problem.

I need to merge multiple detection histories with replacement. These data frames are all equal in size (80 records, and 25 columns). Columns 1-12 of each sheet describe the sites and contain the same values for each data frame. Columns 13-25 contain the response variable for detection/nondetection data at a given site. Values within the detection columns can be NA, 0, or 1. When merging, I need to replace NAs with any 0 or 1 values, and 0 values with any 1 values. Basically, 1 > 0 > NA.

I tried to illustrate my goals for the merge below.

For Example, if I wanted to merge/replace df1 and df2 below...

```
df1     d1 d2 d3
site1   0  1  1
site2   0  NA NA 
site3   0  0  0
site4   1  NA NA

df2     d1 d2 d3
site1   0  0  NA
site2   0  1  0 
site3   0  0  NA
site4   1  0  NA
```

I need to end up with...

```
df3     d1 d2 d3
site1   0  1  1
site2   0  1  0 
site3   0  0  0
site4   1  0  NA
```

Suggested code would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you post your example data using `dput()`? It will make your example copy/pasteable and make it easier to help you. Editing `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` into your question is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get this with a simple `pmax` (parallel maximum). It most naturally works on matrices, not data frames. Using @R Schifini's data:

```
pmax(as.matrix(df1), as.matrix(df2), na.rm = T)
#      d1 d2 d3
# [1,]  0  1  1
# [2,]  0  1  0
# [3,]  0  0  0
# [4,]  1  0 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

Using your data frames as example:

```
df1 = data.frame(d1=c(0,0,0, 1), d2=c(1,NA,0,NA), d3=c(1,NA,0,NA))
df2 = data.frame(d1=c(0,0,0, 1), d2=c(0,1,0,0), d3=c(NA,0,NA,NA))
```

Use this:

```
df2[is.na(df2)] = df1[is.na(df2)]
df2[df1>df2 & !is.na(df1)] = df1[df1>df2 & !is.na(df1)]
```

Result:

```
> df2
  d1 d2 d3
1  0  1  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  0
4  1  0 NA
```

This will replace all NA from df2 using the value in df1. Then it will replace 0 with 1 in those places where df1 is larger and not NA.